# Paypal REST API: Any receipt for Payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am wondering when I pay using [REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create), are there any email receipts? When I try using Sandbox accounts, it appears there are none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the REST API there are e-mail receipts sent (Basic PayPal payment email). However in sandbox mode they do not send e-mail receipts.

If you wish for your emails to be more custom I recommend looking into SendGrid for automating e-mails. I used them in my last project to send 500+ transactional emails out a day.